# P/Invoke WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus from wlanapi.dll

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, pinvoke

I have mapped C++ function (from WLanapi.dll):

```
    DWORD WINAPI WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(
      _In_        HANDLE hClientHandle,
      _Out_       PWLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS *ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus,
      _Reserved_  PVOID pvReserved
    );
```

To the following C# code:

```
    [DllImport("Wlanapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern UInt32 WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(
        [In] IntPtr hClientHandle,
        [Out] out _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus,
        [In, Out] IntPtr pvReserved
        );
```

I have also mapped all the structs and enums required and other stuff (for example to get the clientHandle pointer and to start the hosted network).
The _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS is mapped like so:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS
    {
        public _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATE HostedNetworkState;
        public Guid IPDeviceID;
        public _DOT11_MAC_ADDRESS wlanHostedNetworkBSSID;
        public _DOT11_PHY_TYPE dot11PhyType;
        public UInt32 ulChannelFrequency;
        public UInt32 dwNumberOfPeers;
        public _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE[] PeerList;
    }
```

Now when executing that function, I am not sure how to use ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus correctly and such. The function returns ERROR_SUCCESS (0) which means I have called it and passed parameters correctly as far as I am concerned:

```
    _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS netStatus = new _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS();

    WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(clientHandle, out netStatus, IntPtr.Zero);
```

But while querying ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus for values (like state of the network, or number of connected peers) I am getting just some strange long integers (I would say memory addresses, but I am not sure), for example call:

```
netStatus.HostedNetworkState.ToString();
```

Returns

> 11465720

HostedNetworkState is an enumeration defined like:

```
    public enum _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATE
    {
        wlan_hosted_network_unavailable,
        wlan_hosted_network_idle,
        wlan_hosted_network_active
    }
```

So .toString() should have returned one of these strings from the enumeration, right?
I am pretty sure it is something to do with pointers etc, since in the documentation of the _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS ( [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd439493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ) it says that before the call to that function, the ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus should be a NULL, and that it is itself a pointer to the structure...

How can I debug it? I am coding in C#, VS 2012...

Thanks for your help.

-----EDIT-----
I further tried to map the function with IntPtr as an argument, pass IntPtr.Zero and Marshal.PtrToStruct, but I am getting AccessViolationException when trying to do that...

```
    [DllImport("Wlanapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern UInt32 WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(
        [In] IntPtr hClientHandle,
        [Out] out IntPtr ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus,
        [In, Out] IntPtr pvReserved
        );
```

And then:

```
    IntPtr ppStatus = IntPtr.Zero;

    WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(clientHandle, out ppStatus, IntPtr.Zero);

    _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS netStatus = (_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ppStatus, typeof(_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS));
```

------EDIT 2-------

Following advice from Fermat2357, I have uncommented part of the struct to map, and change the following to count for a pointer to pointer:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS
    {
        public _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATE HostedNetworkState;
        public Guid IPDeviceID;
        public _DOT11_MAC_ADDRESS wlanHostedNetworkBSSID;
        public _DOT11_PHY_TYPE dot11PhyType;
        public UInt32 ulChannelFrequency;
        public UInt32 dwNumberOfPeers;
        //public _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE[] PeerList;
    }
```

I call it like this:

```
    IntPtr ppStatus = IntPtr.Zero;
    WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(clientHandle, out ppStatus, IntPtr.Zero);
    IntPtr ppStatus2 = new IntPtr(ppStatus.ToInt32());
    _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS stat = (_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ppStatus2, typeof(_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS));
    netStatus = stat.HostedNetworkState.ToString();
```

This finally gives me the correct network status (active after starting it)... Now I have to find a way to marshal that dynamic array...
Thanks so far for help Fermat2357

Comment: You should post all the code (mapped structure too).

Comment: I have added the structure, and an example of output of a call of the method...

Comment: Try calling your method without allocating `_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS` first. I don't know if it will work but worth a shot.

Comment: Tried it... the same outcome... it seems as instead of the structure, I am getting an address of memory where that structure is

Comment: You are right, what you get back is a pointer to the buffer holding the desired information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is incorrect. Take a look at the definition of the API function [WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
DWORD WINAPI WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(
  _In_        HANDLE hClientHandle,
  _Out_       PWLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS *ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus,
  _Reserved_  PVOID pvReserved
);
```

Please take care, the parameter `ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus` is a pointer to a pointer to a `WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS` structure.
Take a deeper look in the documentation of the function you will find

> ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus [out]
>
> On input, this parameter must be NULL.
>
> On output, this parameter receives a pointer to the current status of the wireless Hosted Network, if the call to the WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus function succeeds. The current status is returned in a WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS structure.

If you give in a `NULL` pointer (as described in the documentation) the underlying API will allocate a buffer for you holding the structure and initializing the pointer to this buffer. Later dont forget to free it by a call to `WlanFreeMemory`. Otherwise you will have a resource leak here.

<strike>However the documentation seems to be not 100% complete for this function. In my tests (Win7 32Bit) the API will not allocate memory for you if you intitalize the pointer to a enough big memory buffer. In this case a later call to `WlanFreeMemory` seems not be necessary. But in this case its hard to guess how much memory you need for the following `WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE` structures. For that reason this seems not to be useable anyway.</strike>

Here is the C code I used for testing

```
#include <Wlanapi.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD dwRes;
    HANDLE hHandle;
    DWORD negotiatedVersion;

    dwRes = WlanOpenHandle(1, NULL, &negotiatedVersion, &hHandle);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == dwRes)
    {
        PWLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS pStatus = NULL;

        dwRes = WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(hHandle, &pStatus, NULL);
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS == dwRes)
        {
            if (wlan_hosted_network_unavailable != pStatus->HostedNetworkState)
            {
                // Do something with the result
            }

            WlanFreeMemory(pStatus);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle Error
        }

        WlanCloseHandle(hHandle, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        // handle Error
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to make your sample work you need to modify the way you marshal the structure.

**Edit**

To marshal correctly you can try the following:

```
...
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS
{
    public _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATE HostedNetworkState;
    public Guid IPDeviceID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
    public string wlanHostedNetworkBSSID;
    public _DOT11_PHY_TYPE dot11PhyType;
    public UInt32 ulChannelFrequency;
    public UInt32 dwNumberOfPeers;
    public _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE PeerList;
}

...

IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();
uint hostedNetworkQueryStatusSuccess = WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(clientHandle, out ptr, IntPtr.Zero);
if (openHandleSuccess == 0)
{
    var netStat = (_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS));
    Console.WriteLine(netStat.HostedNetworkState);

    if (netStat.HostedNetworkState != _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATE.wlan_hosted_network_unavailable)
    {
        IntPtr offset = Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS), "PeerList");

        for (int i = 0; i < netStat.dwNumberOfPeers; i++)
        {
            var peer = (_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
            new IntPtr(ptr.ToInt64() + offset.ToInt64()), 
            typeof(_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE));

            System.Console.WriteLine(peer.PeerMacAddress);

            offset += Marshal.SizeOf(peer);
        }
    }
}
```

The Idea: Im using a structure here that I can be sure it is marshaled correctly all the time. Later with the knowledge of the `dwNumberOfPeers`  member (if it is valid) I get all the inner structures step by step.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am aware that it is a pointer to a structure returned by the function. And I have seen in the documentation that on the input, it supposed to be NULL. The thing is - I am not sure how to resolve that in C#, since according to the official documentation pointer to a structure you just map as "[Out] out _structure var_name"...

Comment: The problem is it is a double pointer. You can take a search on the web about marshaling double pointer and you will see it is not as trivial as it seems. The best chance is to marshal this parameter as a `out IntPtr ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus` and later using `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to get the structure itself and later also the inner structures. Another way would be to write a Wrapper dll in C++ and use this instead.

Comment: I have tried the IntPtr and Marshal.PtrToStructure without any luck, instead I have got AccessViolationException error (see my original post under --EDIT-- section)...

Comment: I guess the problem occurs with the struct member `public _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE[] PeerList;` please note therefor the struct is somehow dynamic in size. Of course pinvoke cannot manage this automatic. Please try first to uncomment this member and let me know if the access violation disappears.

Comment: When I comment out the array everything works fine, check out -Edit 2- in my original post... I need that array though to get the list of connected peers... Looking into how to map it right now... thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: I updated my answer, but be warned I had no way to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: One thing to try is a trick I use to help debugging - replace your struct with a byte array, and see what you pull back (ok, in this case a uint array):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 48)]
    public uint[] scratch;
}
```

I get very strange values when I run this locally, however - the first (10x4) = 40 bytes are zeroed out:

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 4D454D4C 28 
16DCD870 0 787F6447 80000020 
...omitted...
```

Try this set of P/Invoke declarations:

(done in LINQPad, so replace "Dump" method accordingly)

```
void Main()
{
    IntPtr clientHandle;
    int negotiatedVersion;
    if(WlanOpenHandle(2, IntPtr.Zero, out negotiatedVersion, out clientHandle) != 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not open handle");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Negotiated version:{0}", negotiatedVersion);
    IntPtr pNetStatus = IntPtr.Zero;
    if(WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(clientHandle, out pNetStatus, IntPtr.Zero) != 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not query network status");
    }
    var netStatus = (WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pNetStatus, typeof(WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS));
    Console.WriteLine(netStatus.PeerList[0]);
    WlanFreeMemory(pNetStatus);
    WlanCloseHandle(clientHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
}


[DllImport("Wlanapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool WlanOpenHandle(
  [In] int dwClientVersion,
  IntPtr pReserved,
  [Out] out int pdwNegotiatedVersion,
  [Out] out IntPtr phClientHandle
);
[DllImport("Wlanapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool WlanCloseHandle(
  [In] IntPtr hClientHandle,
  IntPtr pReserved
);
[DllImport("Wlanapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern UInt32 WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(
    [In] IntPtr hClientHandle,
    [Out] out IntPtr ppWlanHostedNetworkStatus,
    [In, Out] IntPtr pvReserved
);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS
{
    public _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATE HostedNetworkState;
    public Guid IPDeviceID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=6)]
    public string wlanHostedNetworkBSSID;
    public _DOT11_PHY_TYPE dot11PhyType;
    public UInt32 ulChannelFrequency;
    public UInt32 dwNumberOfPeers;
    public IntPtr PeerList;
}
public enum _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATE 
{ 
  wlan_hosted_network_unavailable,
  wlan_hosted_network_idle,
  wlan_hosted_network_active
}
public enum _DOT11_PHY_TYPE : uint
{ 
  dot11_phy_type_unknown     = 0,
  dot11_phy_type_any         = 0,
  dot11_phy_type_fhss        = 1,
  dot11_phy_type_dsss        = 2,
  dot11_phy_type_irbaseband  = 3,
  dot11_phy_type_ofdm        = 4,
  dot11_phy_type_hrdsss      = 5,
  dot11_phy_type_erp         = 6,
  dot11_phy_type_ht          = 7,
  dot11_phy_type_IHV_start   = 0x80000000,
  dot11_phy_type_IHV_end     = 0xffffffff
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE 
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=6)]
    public string PeerMacAddress;
    _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_AUTH_STATE PeerAuthState;
}
public enum _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_AUTH_STATE 
{ 
  wlan_hosted_network_peer_state_invalid,
  wlan_hosted_network_peer_state_authenticated
}
```

Comment: Some is looking very good but some seems to be incorrect. The most big problem I see is how you can know the full size of the `netStat` structure a priori? Take care because it is followed by an array of `_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE` where the length will be specified in `dwNumberOfPeers`. And again here you dont marshal a pointer to a pointer to the `netstat` structure.

Comment: All the mappings look the same as mine, with little differences which should not have impact on the fact if I can use the struct or not...

Comment: @Fermat2357 Most of those declarations came straight out of the interop assistant, barring a couple changes I made for readability - you are, of course, absolutely correct about the pointer-to-pointer mistake: I must have dropped an asterisk when typing in the signatures...